# Core Data - Get managed object by URI

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm trying to fetch managed objects from Core Data by their URI. For this I found an Objective-C example of a method (http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/safely-fetching-nsmanagedobject-by-uri.html) and converted it to Swift ...

```
func getManagedObjectWithURI(uri:NSURL) -> NSManagedObject?
{
    if let psc = persistentStoreCoordinator
    {
        let objID = psc.managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation(uri);
        if (objID != nil)
        {
            let obj:NSManagedObject = managedObjectContext!.objectWithID(objID!);

            if (!obj.fault)
            {
                return obj;
            }

            let prd = NSComparisonPredicate(leftExpression: .expressionForEvaluatedObject(), rightExpression: NSExpression(forConstantValue: obj), modifier: .DirectPredicateModifier, type: .EqualToPredicateOperatorType, options: .allZeros);

            let req = NSFetchRequest();
            req.entity = objID?.entity;
            req.predicate = prd;

            var results:[NSManagedObject] = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(req, error: nil) as! [NSManagedObject];

            if (!results.isEmpty)
            {
                return results.first;
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

However the method always returns nil, i.e. the  fetch request returns empty-handed and I don't know why. Up to the NSFetchRequest everything looks valid. Does anyone has an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. It was actually related to another, deeper problem in my core data code explained here: [Mac OSX - Core data isn't stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033027/mac-osx-core-data-isnt-stored/30034984#30034984)

The above method works fine otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the entity and the predicate contain the expected values.

Another suggestion is to write your predicate with `NSPredicate(format:)` for clarity.

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self = %@", object)
```

*I have changed your variable names for readability.*

Comment: NSFetchRequest is a reference type, so "let" vs "var" does not make any difference (and "let" is preferred unless you need to assign another request to the `req` variable later).

Comment: Nope, still no luck. Also after trying it with the predicate string format. I added the debug output of the predicate and entity above, in case there is anything suspicious in these. I lack the experience with Core Data too see anything in it that could be wrong.

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with my core data implementation. It tells me it has no changes when trying to save, even though it should (NSArrayControllers are populated that are set to use CoreData). That might have something to do with the above issue.